# Conflict between ElasticSearch mapping and data via Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

What happens if some data being input via logstash into ElasticSearch does not conform to the mapping defined in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

The default is to "coerce" the data into the defined mapping, so inserting a string value of "1" into an integer field will work - Elasticsearch can convert it.

If you insert "foo" into an integer field, the document is typically dropped and the fact will be logged in the elasticsearch logs.